# What would be a barely-adequate portable virtual machine?

Tags: windows, virtual-machines

I want set up a virtual machine on a thumb drive and load it down with tools for repairing borked Windows installations. I figure i need just enough to piggy-back on the machine's installed drivers 'till i can download new ones. So first, I need to decide which VM software to use. Anything that'll get the job done, no bells and/or whistles needed.

Comment: Do you want the guest and host to both live on the thumb drive?  Are you trying to use the borked Windows install as the host?  Why not just have a non-virtual OS on the thumb drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[QEMU for Windows](http://www.h7.dion.ne.jp/~qemu-win/) or [QEMU](http://www.nongnu.org/qemu/) is very portable, but slow. Should be fine for a no-frills machine. After that, [Damn Small Linux](http://damnsmalllinux.org/) is quite good, or do a custom [Gentoo](http://www.gentoo.org/) install (is there any other kind? :D).

Answer (score 4):

Wouldn't a bootable Linux "live CD" (such as [Knoppix](http://www.knoppix.net/), [Ubuntu](http://ubuntu.com)), or a [BartPE](http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/) disc be a better solution? If the system is "borked", surely it's going to struggle to run any VM software..

It also means you can access/edit/delete files that would otherwise be locked

Answer (score 1):

There are a few to choose from in this little project - [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/#features).